# Are there any places to get highly graphical/visual math videos, specifically for calculus?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, multivariable-calculus

I love watching National Geographic and Discovery channel pieces on the universe/outer space because they are so visually appealing, but if I had to read about the topics, I wouldn't have much interest.  Are there any places that have math videos that are highly CGI, that help visualize calculus concepts?  (specifically, I'm in vector calc this term.)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The episodes of [The Mechanical Universe](http://www.learner.org/resources/series42.html) about the derivative and integration are pretty good. (They're where I originally learned about differentiation and integration, before the BC calc course)

Comment: Also, this really great documentary about the birth of the calculus recently was mentioned: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ObPg3ki9GOI

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not exactly a "movie", but an excellent way to visualize vector calculus stuff is to play around with Mathematica and/or Maple. Both of these packages have extensive graphing/animation capabilities for all types of graphs (parametric equations, vector fields, etc.) that can reveal the nature of the vector fields/surfaces, etc. that you encounter.

See [here](http://www.math.usu.edu/~powell/math320/labbk.html), for an example of some "computational labs" put together for Mathematica. Although I haven't seen it, [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0618439242) is a book on doing vector calculus with Maple.

Comment: yeah I've used those, but I was looking for more of a video-style that I could watch in free time.  thanks though!